# disabling options in a dropdown based on another dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I  am trying to disable/remove options in a dropdown, based on the selection of other dropdown options. 
But the dropdown/selector we have to choose from, has a sub-dropdown list and both main and sub dropdowns are 
sharing the same classes and ids but since both are wrapped in different divs with different ids, I have been 
trying to access the second selector but couldn't . 
Below is the js code that I used for this;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("lvl1").querySelector("select").onchange = function() 
{
    if(this.value=="8"){
        var bikeSizes = document.getElementById("pa_size[]");
        for ( var i = 1; i <8; i++) {
            bikeSizes.options[i].removeAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
        }
        for ( var i = 8; i < 12; i++) {
            bikeSizes.options[i].setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    } else {
        var bikeSizes = document.getElementById("pa_size[]");
        for ( var i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
            bikeSizes.options[i].setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
        }
        for ( var i = 8; i < 12; i++) {
            bikeSizes.options[i].removeAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    }
    return false;
};
</script>
```

The html code of the selector/dropdowns are;

— Select —
     Camping
     Road Sports
     Snow Sports
     Water Sports

```
 <div id="lvl1" level="1" style="">
 <select data-required="yes" data-type="select" name="product_cat" id="product_cat" class="cat-ajax product_cat wpuf_product_cat_">
 <option value="-1">— Select —</option>
 <option class="level-0" value="8">Bikes</option>
 </select>
 <span data-taxonomy="{&quot;required&quot;:&quot;yes&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;product_cat&quot;,&quot;exclude_type&quot;:&quot;child_of&quot;,&quot;exclude&quot;:&quot;camping,road-sports,water-sports&quot;,&quot;orderby&quot;:&quot;name&quot;,&quot;order&quot;:&quot;ASC&quot;}"></span>
 </div>
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to add the html code:

Comment: add your html too

Comment: You can add it... There is an edit link below your question.

Comment: thnx I added it there

Comment: document.getElementById("lvl1").querySelector("select).onchange = function() 
{
   missing a quote

Comment: @Bindrid .querySelector("select")  btw, that quote is not an issue I missed it while copying

Comment: if the above javascript is above the html you must be getting an undefined error when the page is loading.  Put it inside an onload function if that is the case

Comment: Personally, since the two parts of the same select box are mutually exclusive, I would put them in separate select boxes and use the event handler to show or hide the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the quote then put it in an onload function.  Also, there is no second argument on a removeAttribute.  This worked for me.

```
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById("product_cat").onchange = function () {
            if (this.value == "8") {
                var bikeSizes = document.getElementById("pa_size[]");
                for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
                    bikeSizes.options[i].removeAttribute("disabled");
                }
                for (var i = 8; i < 12; i++) {
                    bikeSizes.options[i].setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
                }
            } else {
                var bikeSizes = document.getElementById("pa_size[]");
                for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
                    bikeSizes.options[i].setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
                }
                for (var i = 8; i < 12; i++) {
                    bikeSizes.options[i].removeAttribute("disabled");
                }
            }
            return false;
        };
    }
</script>


<!-- my test html  -->

<div id="lvl1" level="1" style="">
    <select data-required="yes" data-type="select" name="product_cat" id="product_cat" class="cat-ajax product_cat wpuf_product_cat_">
        <option value="-1">— Select —</option>
        <option class="level-0" value="8">Bikes</option>
    </select>
    <span data-taxonomy="{&quot;required&quot;:&quot;yes&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;product_cat&quot;,&quot;exclude_type&quot;:&quot;child_of&quot;,&quot;exclude&quot;:&quot;camping,road-sports,water-sports&quot;,&quot;orderby&quot;:&quot;name&quot;,&quot;order&quot;:&quot;ASC&quot;}"></span>

<select id="pa_size[]">
    <option value="-1">--Select--</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
</select>
  </div>
```

Comment: as described that I have tried that solution but somehow it is not working as it should. As it should work with the sub-dropdown list that appears after selecting any option from "Ride Category" dropdown. Here is the url so that you may see what I want to accomplish: http://development.tripoutside.com/add-new-listing/

Comment: I looked at your website and how you are using the above code. It will not work. Hiding the option element only works in some browsers, most just ignore it.

Comment: I will take another look at it tonight.  I am at work right now

Comment: highly appreciate your support, looking forward to your input

Comment: So one question, what selects should be visible and what should not be visible when the user clicks the next button to get to the page with these select boxes on them before taking any action.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I saw on your website, here is an alternative solution:

```
   <script>

        var group1 = [ { value:"33", text:"Small Unisex"},
         { value:"34", text:"Large Unisex"},
         { value:"35", text:"XL Unisex"},
         { value:"36", text:"Small Womens"},
         { value:"37", text:"Medium Womens"},
         { value:"38", text:"Large Womens"},
         { value:"39", text:"XL Womens"}];

        var group2 = [{value:"40", text:"Medium"},
        {value:"41", text:"Small"},
        { value:"43", text:"XL"},
        { value:"42", text:"Large"}];


        window.onload = function() {
            document.getElementById("product_cat").onchange = function () {
                var bikeSizes = document.getElementById("pa_size[]");
                bikeSizes.innerHTML = "";
                bikeSizes.appendChild(new Option("--Select--", "-1"));
                bikeSizes.disabled = false;

                if (this.value == "-1") {
                    bikeSizes.disabled = true;
                }
                else if (this.value == "8") {
                    for (var i = 0; i < group1.length; ++i){
                        var opt = new Option(group1[i].text, group1[i].value);
                        bikeSizes.appendChild(opt);
                    }

                } else  {
                    for (var i = 0; i < group2.length; ++i) {
                        var opt = new Option(group2[i].text, group2[i].value);
                        bikeSizes.appendChild(opt);
                    }
                }
                return false;
            };
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: your suggestions are highly appreciated, but code is not working, because the js function should be invoked when the sub-dropdown appears.

Comment: the javascript function should call upon only if the sub or child dropdown is visible. So, I guess we need a function that invokes the js function when the child dropdown loads.

Comment: I have an alternative if you include jquery.js.  That would allow you to assign event handlers even before the select boxes are visible.

Answer (score 0):

so is this closer to what you need?  This is 3 select boxes where you can only see the second one after the first one has a valid selection.  Then you can only see the third one when the second one has a valid choice.

The options available is dependent on its master select box.

you can see it work here http://jsbin.com/nijahoh/edit?html,js,output

```
    <script>

        var fakeData = {
            group1: [{ value: "group3", text: "3" }, { value: "group4", text: "4" }],
            group2: [{ value: "group5", text: "5" }, { value: "group6", text: "6" }],
            group3: [{ value: "group7", text: "7" }, { value: "group8", text: "8" }],
            group4: [{ value: "group9", text: "9" }, { value: "group10", text: "10" }]

        };


        $(document).ready(function(){

            // first select box change handler
            $("#product_cat").on("change", function () {
                var val = this.value;
                $("#d").val("-1");
                setUpSel($("#d"), val);
                $("#d").trigger("change");
                $("#d").css("display", val=="-1"?"none":"");
            });

            $("#d").on("change", function () {
                var val = this.value;
                $("#c").val("-1");
                setUpSel($("#c"), val);
                $("#c").trigger("change");
                $("#c").css("display", val == "-1" ? "none" : "");
            });

        });
        function setUpSel($sel, group) {
            $sel.html("<option value='-1'>--Select--</option>");
            var selData = fakeData[group];
            $.each(selData, function (i, opt) {
                $sel.append(new Option(opt.text, opt.value));
            });

        }

    </script>
```

Comment: I can try this but I don't think it gonna work, because in this solution the select is available there but its just hidden through css propert "display:none;" where on actual site the select is not available there physically and it appends/load when any selection is made in the main dropdown which is "Ride category" on the site

Comment: I updated jsbin so that the second two select boxes do not exist until their master select box is set the first time. The event handlers have been modified slightly. http://jsbin.com/nijahoh/8/edit

Comment: There is a  little bit of redundant code but left that there for clarity.

Comment: what is uses to actually trigger the data fetch that creates the second select box? What ever is used should have a callback function that would allow you to push the data into a local json object and populate the select box as needed.

Comment: the 2nd select box is the sub-category of the rental products to be added.
And we are unable to locate that function that displays the second and 3rd dropbox.